# Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,bool>

Tags: c#, generics, dictionary

This code works fine

```
Dictionary<string, bool> test = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
        test.Add("test string", true);
```

The following code throws this error : Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary

```
Dictionary<string, bool> test = new Dictionary<string, bool>().Add("test string", true);
```

why? what is the difference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The return type of `.Add` is `void`

If you are chaining calls, the last expression becomes the return value of the whole statement.

The return value of `new Dictionary<K, V>()` is `Dictionary<K, V>`, then you call `.Add` on it and `.Add` returns nothing (`void`)

You can use object initialiser syntax to do this inline:

```
Dictionary<string, bool> test = new Dictionary<string, bool> 
{ 
    { "test string", true } 
};
```

Edit: more info, a lot of fluent syntax style frameworks will return the object you called the method on to allow you to chain:

e.g.

```
public class SomeFluentThing 
{
   public SomeFluentThing DoSomething()
   {
       // Do stuff
       return this;
   }

   public SomeFluentThing DoSomethingElse()
   {
       // Do stuff
       return this;
   }

}
```

So you can chain naturally:

```
SomeFluentThingVariable.DoSomething().DoSomethingElse();
```

Comment: agh.. forgot to check return types. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The returned value type of `Add()` method is not a object of Dictionary class. Also you cannot Assign the output of the Add() method to test object.

for example you **cannot** use this code:

```
Dictionary<string, bool> test = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
test = test.Add("test string", true); // Error
```

Answer (score 0):

The return type for `Add()` is `void`

so `new Dictionary<string, bool>().Add("test string", true);` is void that you are assigning to `Dictionary<string, bool> test`, which caused your error.

```
Dictionary<string, bool> test = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
test.Add("test string", true);
```

on the other hand assigns new `Dictionary` to `test` and latter performs the `Add`

Answer (score 0):

As Ali Sephri.Kh said, while

```
new Dictionary<string, bool>();
```

return a Dictionary instance, therefore your new variable can be assigned to it, the Add method adds a new value to the new dictionary, and returns void, therefore can not be assigned to your new variable